# video not stoping when modal closed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog

on the following page https://yourhippo.com/course-search/ I'm trying to get the video to stop when the modal closes I'm not sure what the best option for closing the video is I've  tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
  '''( function( w, d ) {
      'use strict';
       // Get the modal
      var el = d.getElementsByClassName( 'container' )[0];
       var modal = d.getElementById( 'id01' );
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
       w.onclick = function ( event ) {
        if ( event.target == modal ) {
           modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
      };
   d.getElementsByClassName( 'close' )[0].addEventListener( 'click',
      function() {
         d.getElementById( 'id01' ).style.display = 'none';
         while ( el.firstChild ) {
                 el.removeChild( el.firstChild ); 
      }
     }, false );

    }( window, document ));'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .pause() method.

```html
<!-- Add the vimeo api. -->
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe'); // the iframe that is already in your HTML
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe); // init the vimeo video player
 
player.pause() // pauses the video
```

```js
( function( w, d ) {
      'use strict';
       // Get the modal
      var el = d.getElementsByClassName( 'container' )[0];
       var modal = d.getElementById( 'id01' );
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
       w.onclick = function ( event ) {
        if ( event.target == modal ) {
           modal.style.display = 'none';
           var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe'); // the iframe that is already in your HTML
           var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe); // init the vimeo video player
           player.pause() // pauses the video
        }
      };
   d.getElementsByClassName( 'close' )[0].addEventListener( 'click',
      function() {
         d.getElementById( 'id01' ).style.display = 'none';
         while ( el.firstChild ) {
                 el.removeChild( el.firstChild ); 
      }
     }, false );

    }( window, document ));
```

[Source](https://codetogo.io/how-to-stop-video-in-javascript/)

Comment: I've added this but it doesn't seem to stop the video playing when I close the modal if you play the video on adult support and protection and then close the modal it still plays https://yourhippo.com/course-search/

Comment: @user3565700 Sorry, I didn't see the player you're using is a Vimeo player. For more info on using the Vimeo player visit: [https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/)

Comment: so what would i be looking for on there sorry not great with js

Comment: I've updated my answer and code block. I hope you understand.

Comment: so this is the code I'm inputting the modal with am I right in thinking I've done this right if I just add your code into my javascript file? sorry for all the questions

'''<div class="aims-objectives-modal" id="modal-[wpv-post-id]">
      <button class="modal-close" onclick="hideModal([wpv-post-id])">X</button>
      [wpv-conditional if="( $(demo_video_yn) eq '1' )"]
      <div class="modal-video">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/[wpv-post-field name="demo_vimeo_video_id"]" frameborder="0" allow=" fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>'''

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong or not but the video is still playing  when I close the modal could you give any pointers